# ALB _and_ EC2 instances have to be on multiple AZs?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

For an ALB (which has a security group containing more than one AZ for HA) to make sense, the EC2 instances in the ALB's target group ALSO have to be living on more than one AZ, is that correct?

Otherwise, if all instances are in the same AZ but the ALB supports multiple AZs, this doesn't make sense, am I getting this right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ALB's target group ALSO have to be living on more than one AZ, is that correct?

It is incorrect. You **don't have to** place them in more than one 1 AZ. But they still have to be at least in one of the AZs enabled for the ALB - it can't be a different AZ.

And the reason why you don't have to do it, is because for ALB [cross-zone load balancing](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/userguide/how-elastic-load-balancing-works.html) is **always enabled**:

> When cross-zone load balancing is enabled, each load balancer node distributes traffic **across** the registered targets in **all enabled** Availability Zones.
> With Application Load Balancers, cross-zone load balancing is **always enabled**.

> this doesn't make sense, am I getting this right?

Sort of. You ALB requires two AZs for HA. Thus, placing all instances in one of them is not really recommended. But sometimes you have to do it. An example is that your instances in ASG share a pool of EBS volumes. EBS volumes have zonal scope, so you have to bound all your instances to a single AZ.